# How to show the output of a function that takes two arguments in brython?

Tags: javascript, python

I have this brython script that is supposed to take in two inputs, process them in a python function imported from another python file, and generate one output into a textarea when the inputs are typed in. I can't figure out how to do that as the `bind()` only allows one.

[Here is how the process looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzeg.png)

The following code only works with one input

```
<textarea id="input_one"></textarea>
<textarea id="input_two"></textarea>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<script type="text/python">
    import project
    from browser import document
    def function(x):
        document['output'].text = project.main(x.target.value)
    document['input_one'].bind('input', function)            
</script>
```

Comment: What other input argument do you want to pass to the function?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen The function is supposed to be function(x,y) with x and y are document['input_one'] and document['input_two'] respectively as project.main() actually can takes two inputs x and y.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to bind to a shared parent (eg. a `<form />` element)

Comment: Thank you. Previously I tried to bind both of them to list and tuple and that didn't work as they don't change in real-time. Maybe <form/> can work

Answer (score 1):

Assign names to the fields in the document and refer to them in the bound function.
That way you can retrieve their values and pass them along to `project.main`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.10.7/brython.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.10.7/brython_stdlib.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="brython()">

<script type="text/python">

from browser import document
import project 

element_x = document['input_one']
element_y = document['input_two']
element_result = document['output']

def oninput(arg):
    x, y = None, None
    try:
        x = int(element_x.value)
        y = int(element_y.value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    if x and y:
        element_result.value =  project.main(x, y)
    else:
        element_result.value = ''

element_x.bind('input', oninput)
element_y.bind('input', oninput)
</script>

<input id="input_one"></input>
<input id="input_two"></input>
<input id="output" disabled></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It's not the project.main() problem as when I tried to replace project.main() with x+y, it didn't work.

Comment: Check out the [repl](https://replit.com/@oluwafemisule/brython#index.html) and see if you missed something.

Comment: Are you able to run the [tutorial example](https://brython.info/static_tutorial/en/index.html) on your machine?

Comment: Thank you. Turns out that I have set the variable x and y before.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. 